# SOAP request JavaScript in Browser not giving response

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, xmlhttprequest, request

I am  trying to access SOAP service hosted in  the server using my Chrome browser in window 7 . I have tested the same service and soap action in SOAPUI and  getting response and also in android using icesoap and getting the right response from the server  ,Now I am wishing to get the response in browser with the following code written in java script to do the same , so that i can implement further , and it is giving me undefined error with ie xmlHttp.status == 0

The following code I used and saved as HTML file in window desktop( ***c:/Users/vipin.sahu.OM/Desktop/New folder/soap.html***) and run it into browser

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soap() {   
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();            
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://65.17.222.114/t2green/servicecontract/Courses.svc?wsdl", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/ICourses/GetCountries");
        // build SOAP request
        var sr ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">'+
            '<soapenv:Header/>'+
            '<soapenv:Body>'+
            '<tem:GetCountries>'+
            '</tem:GetCountries>'+
            '</soapenv:Body>'+
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.onerror = function(e) {
        alert("Error ocurred. Error = " + e.message);
        }

        xmlhttp.ontimeout = function(e) {
        alert("Timeout error!");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {  
            if (xmlhttp.readyState  == 4) {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200 || xmlHttp.status == 0) {

                alert(xmlhttp.status);

                    }
                    else{
                     alert(xmlhttp.status);
                     }
                }   
                else{
                 alert('error in response');
            }

          } 

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", sr.length);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        xmlhttp.send(sr);  


        }
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">   
    function test(){        
    alert('ok alert is still  working');
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
    <div>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="test()" />    
    <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap()" />   
    </div>
    </form>
   </body>
   <html>


Here are following url and action I used in android and getting requisite response
```

**URL** "http://65.17.222.114/t2green/servicecontract/courses.svc"

**Soap_action** "http://tempuri.org/ICourses/GetCountries"

**Request** –

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:GetCountries/>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you work with session Authentification on IceSoap ? (sory for the question)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the the same origin policy applied by Chrome.
This means that you cannot make requests from a local (file://) URL to the remote web-service.

Use the `--allow-file-access-from-files` command-line flag when starting Chrome to remove this restriction, as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677/1972476

Comment: If you do that though you cannot ensure your clients are doing it.  It would be better to call the service from your server and send the response back to your javascript.

Comment: thanks .yup how can i test it then .. is there any server for that .

Comment: I would imagine that clients will not have just a local file like in this (development) scenario. You will have to host it using a web server (Apache, lighttpd) where the URL matches same origin policy constraints for the web service URL (the hard-coded IP may be an issue)